# How do you build a referenced solution, when your current solution is built in Visual Studio?

Tags: c#, visual-studio, solution

I have a reference solution, lets call it Utilities. When I build my solution that references Utilities, I would like Utilities to be built as well. I don't want to add Utilities to my current solution though because many other solutions use it as well. I'm using Visual Studios 2015

Comment: The solution is already unit of highest level. In it you can define build order of projects (project dependencies). You don't provide much of details. If second solution is simple, e.g. consisting from just one project, then you can reference same projects in many solutions. Add that project into solution, reference **project** (and not e.g. `dll` produced by solution as you more likely doing now), define build order.

Comment: I would like to make correction, when you say reference solution, do you mean a project, you have a project called ultilities. Further more there is no problem with using the same project from multiple solutions